# Find time periods when the SUM of a column on all records up to that time was a certain value

Tags: sql, postgresql

(I am using PostgreSQL)

I have a table which stores transactions to an account. For the sake of this question imagine it is structured as follows:

```
create table transactions (
    timestamp timestamp with time zone not null,
    amount decimal(6,2) not null
);
```

The balance at any point in time can be obtained by:

```
select sum(amount) as balance from transactions where timestamp < 'point in time';
```

How can I find all periods of time where the balance (the sum of `amount`s up to that point in time) was equal to a certain value (the most interesting value for me being 0, but a general solution would be nice)?

I am aware of the solution that involves denormalising `balance` into its own column. I would prefer not to do that for other reasons, so I am looking for suggestions using the schema above.

Comment: You could do it both by doing a self-join or with windowing functions; both approaches are demonstrated in [this article](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/119-Running-totals-and-sums-using-PostgreSQL-8.4-Windowing-functions.html), which is actually the second hit on Google for `postgres running total` (the first hit is also relevant to your question, though less comprehensive).

Comment: Thanks. I would have Googled for that, if I had the words to describe what I wanted so succinctly! Now I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(amount) over(order by timestamp) as balance, timestamp 
from transactions where timestamp < 'point in time';
```

Find all zero:

```
with a as
(
   select sum(amount) over(order by timestamp) as balance, timestamp
   from transactions where timestamp < 'point in time'
)
select * from a where balance = 0
```